# How to access variables from Readline in a Playground

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

I have a challenge where I'm give two lines of data

> 2 3
>
> 1 2 3 4 5

I have to access this data and get this into two variables (2 and 3) and the second line into an array.  I gather part of this challenge is Reading the line and doing something like:

```
func readIntegers() -> [String] {
    return readLine()!.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").map { $0 }
}
```

how do I enter the data above into a Playground so the I can access it using ReadLine()?  I must do this because this is a requirement of the interface provide by HackRank website but I want to emulate that in Playground.  I currently have the Code Editor and the Debug area visible. Is there data entry pane?

Comment: You can't use `readLine()` in a Playground.

Comment: Can I do it in Xcode then?  If so, how please?

Comment: IMO the simplest is to make a new Cocoa app (and uncheck "visible at launch" for the main window). Otherwise you can make a new command line app.

Comment: @Moritz: In some sense, you can :)

Comment: @MartinR Very nice solution!

Comment: Thanks.  I followed your advice and created a Cocoa app, it works fine, but MartinR has an interesting solution as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect the standard input to read from some file with

```
freopen("/path/to/input.txt", "r", stdin)
```

This works both in a Playground and in a compiled Command Line Tool project. If you want to keep the data in the Playground then

- Open the project navigator (View -> Navigators -> Show Project Navigator (cmd-1)
- Select the “Resources” folder and choose File -> New -> File (cmd-N).
- Select the new file in the project navigator and rename it to “input.txt”.
- Add the input data to this file.

In the Playground, redirect the standard input to read from the
resource file:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "input", ofType: "txt") {
    freopen(path, "r", stdin)
}
```

Now `readLine()` reads from “input.txt”.