# Xcode can't get input

Tags: swift, macos, swift-playground

i want to run a simple code in Xcode but i face some errors

when i run this simple code in Xcode

```
let Name:String? = readLine()
print("Your name is \(Name!)")
```

these errors will be shown
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wriR5.png)

Comment: You can't read user input from a playground, you need a command line app for that.

Comment: Ask yourself what `readLine()` is? Assuming you are doing one of the many practice problems you have to mimic the `readline()` behavior somehow.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/49279446/1187415